# How to open a new page to show additional details or single page in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a FlatList that looks like this

```
  <FlatList
     horizontal={true}
     data={this.state.mydata}
     renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Button onPress={()=>"HOW TO SEE Details? } title="See Details"/>
      </View>
       )}
       keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   />
```

This FlatList loops through the results and is now showing names of the items. Now the Button which i have should open a new window or a page to show additional details. How do I do that in react native? I have been looking at navigation and would stack navigation be the best way to do it? Or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stack navigator should do.

```
<FlatList
 horizontal={true}
 data={this.state.mydata}
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('details_page', {details: item.details})} title="See Details"/>
  </View>
   )}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Just have a details screen in your stack navigator.

However I feel the best way would be to show a full screen [modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) if there is nomore routing to do from details page view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Modal controlled by state in the same page in render() method put the code below :

```
<Modal isVisible={this.state.modalVisible}>
   // Your modal content .....
</Modal>
```

The modalVisible var can take true/false, if true de Modal be showed, Modal is part of react-native-modal.